# SQL joining two columns on single column to get count

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am strugling to figure out how to receive what I need with t-sql. 
My goal is to count distinct operations, which contains certain item code combinations in side of them. 
Final desired output table:

```
SELECT '1' as code_1, '2' as code_2, 2 as op_count INTO #final_table_example UNION
SELECT '2' as code_1, '3' as code_2, 0 as op_count
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have two tables:

Table A is like the output/goal table, but without **[op_count]** *(this is the column I want to calculate)*. 
Table B looks like this:

```
SELECT 'A' as operation, '1' as item_code INTO #operations UNION
SELECT 'A' as operation, '2' as item_code UNION
SELECT 'A' as operation, '3' as item_code UNION
SELECT 'B' as operation, '1' as item_code UNION
SELECT 'B' as operation, '3' as item_code
```

[image]

As you can see my **Table B** has 2 operations that have **1 & 3** item codes in them. 
And only 1 operation have **2 & 3** code combination. 
I need efficient query as I will scan few million operations. 
Many thanks.

Comment: please post data as text

Comment: Isn't this a pivot/conditional aggregation?

Comment: provide your desired result.

Comment: No, [Kendle is not joking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/61305). <-- See the top-rated answer, 1,000+ people agree, only 5 people disagree. Also see https://sqlblog.org/ask and create a [fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle). Basically, you don't want to make it hard for people to help you, or arguing with them on top of that to make them less willing to help you, too.

Comment: Please provide an example of the two tables as they are, without adding extra bits. It currently sounds like you want a ROW_NUMBER partition on the Operation column, but I cant be sure as not seeing example table A and B and expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 queries which show the information that you are looking for.

- The first query is the format requested. It looks for all combinations of 2 codes. If you have operations with many codes the number of rows returned will grow exponentially.
- The second query will group all the item_codes associated with an operation and then count the number of operation with each combination of codes.

NB When we have a query using UNION we only need to give column aliases for the first query as all other aliases will be ignored.

> ```
> SELECT 'A' as operation, '1' as item_code INTO #operations UNION
> SELECT 'A' as operation, '2' as item_code UNION
> SELECT 'A' as operation, '3' as item_code UNION
> SELECT 'B' as operation, '1' as item_code UNION
> SELECT 'B' as operation, '3' as item_code UNION
> SELECT 'C', '1' UNION SELECT 'C','2';
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   a.item_code code_1,
>   b.item_code code_2,
>   count(*) op_count
> from #operations a
> join #operations b on a.item_code < b.item_code
>   and a.operation = b.operation
> group by
>   a.item_code,
>   b.item_code;
> ```

> ```
> code_1 | code_2 | op_count
> :----- | :----- | -------:
> 1      | 2      |        2
> 1      | 3      |        2
> 2      | 3      |        1
> ```

> ```
> ;WITH cte AS 
> (
> SELECT
>   STRING_AGG(item_code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY item_code) AS codes,
>   operation
> FROM #operations 
> GROUP BY operation
> )
> SELECT
>   codes,
>   COUNT(operation) op_count
> FROM cte
> GROUP BY codes;
> ```
>
> ```
> codes | op_count
> :---- | -------:
> 1,2   |        1
> 1,2,3 |        1
> 1,3   |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=ad304c96ceff52315c576e384f126d44)*

Comment: Please don't add quoting format to your fiddle code. A post should be self-contatined. The fiddle is quoting the post. It just adds noise. You don't even make it clear what the quoting is there for. (Some of it seems from the question.)